# Gradient of inner product containing inverse of the sum of two matrices

Tags: derivatives, determinant, inverse, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Given $n \times 1$ vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, I need help determining the gradient

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{A}} \left( \mathbf{x}^{T} \left( \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{y} \right)$$

where $n \times n$ matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are symmetric and positive definite.

I don't believe the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) lists this gradient, but it is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924311/derivative-of-inverse-of-sum-of-matrices). Also, if $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are both symmetric positive definite matrices, then is the following true
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \ln (\det(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}))}{\partial \mathbf{A}} = (\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B})^{-1} ?
\end{align}
This result is based on the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792385/derivative-of-the-determinant-of-the-sum-of-two-matrices).

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\L{\lambda}
\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\p{{\partial}}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\E{{\cal E}}
$For typing convenience define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
M &= M^T = \l(A+B\r) \quad&\implies\quad dM = dA \\
W &= W^T = M^{-1} \quad&\implies\quad dW = -W\,dM\,W \\
}$$
The first function can be analyzed as
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= xy^T:W  \\
d\phi ​&= xy^T:\l(-W\,dM\,W\r)  \\
​&= -Wxy^TW:dA \\
\g{\phi}{A} &= -Wxy^TW \\
}$$
and the second as
$$\eqalign{
​\L &= \log\det M \\
d\L &= M^{-T}:dM \\
   ​&= W:dA \\
\g{\L}{A} &= W \\
}$$
So your proposed formula is correct.

---

In the steps above a colon denotes the trace/inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij}
   \;=\; {\rm Tr}\!\l(AB^T\r) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|_F^2 \\
}$$